# Generating SSH keys (Win/msysgit) - Ruby on Rails Tutorial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, ssh, ssh-keys

I'm following along with Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and I've run into a roadblock trying to generate an SSH key for git.

When I type:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "ben@rockhopperdigital.com"
```

I get this:

```
bash: ssh-keygen: command not found
```

I'm sure it's something stupid, but I'm new to git and Rails in general. Any assistance would be much appreciated (and may garner you a link on my blog). A search for that error in quotations followed by git gave me 0 results on a Google search.

Thanks,

Ben

Comment: Did you install msysgit ? What happens when you type 'git' ?

Comment: mysgit is installed. I was able to use the git log and git configure commands without any trouble.

Answer (score 2):

Which OS are you on? It depends on that. Normally you install openssh package to get the ssh utils which includes ssh-keygen. If you are on debian or ubuntu try to see if you have installed ssh-keygen.

If on windows get openssh for Windows or Putty to generate the key for you.

--Sai

Comment: I'm using cygwin on Windows. I'll give openssh or Putty a try.

Comment: I ended up having to run cygwin's setup.exe again to add the openssh package. That took care of everything. Up and running with git now!